# Using recursion to reverse a dictionary around a value in python

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion

I have a data set which follows the structure of the following example:

```
exampleset = {
    'body' : {
        'abdomen' : [{
            'arms' : {
                'value' : 2,
            }
        },{
            'legs': {
                'value' : 2,
            }
        }],
        'hands' : {
            'fingers' : {
                'value' : 5,
            }
        },
    }                
}
```

I am trying to reverse this so I get something like:

```
{'value': {'value1': {5: {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}},
           'value2': {2: {'legs': {'abdomen': {'body': {}}}}},
           'value3': {2: {'arms': {'abdomen': {'body': {}}}}}},
}
```

(I hope I got the bracket matching right, but you get the idea.)

I am using a couple of recursion functions to do this, like so:

```
def recurse_find(data, values, count):
    global conf
    for key in data:
        for v in conf['value_names']:
            if key == v:
                values[v+str(count)] = {}
                values[v+str(count)][data[key]] = {}
                count += 1
                # originally just using this line:
                # values[data[key]] = {}
        if type(data[key]) is list:
            for i in data[key]:
                if type(i) is dict:
                    values = recurse_find(i, values, count)
                    values = add_new_level(values, key)
        elif type(data[key]) is dict:
            values = recurse_find(data[key], values, count)
            values = add_new_level(values, key)
    return values

def add_new_level(data, new_key):
    for key in data:
        if data[key] == {}:
            data[key][new_key] = {}
        else:
            data[key] = add_new_level(data[key], new_key)
    return data

conf = { "value_names": ["value"] }

for value in conf['value_names']:
    values[value] = recurse_find(exampleset, {}, 1)

print(values)
```

At the moment I only get one value returned correctly, obviously I would like them all. Originally I didn't label the values (value1, value2 etc), but when doing this example set I realised that of course if the values are the same I'll only get one! If I remove the value name keys it finds all the values (unless duplicate) but still doesn't return the correct levels as it includes some of the others  while it loops round. I don't care about the order of the values, just that they are labelled differently so I don't miss out any.

Current result:

```
{'value': {'value1': {5: {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}}}}
```

I think that the solution is the inclusion of a pretty simple step, but I can't see it at the moment and I've already spent too long looking at this.
Any help appreciated.

### EDIT:

I've gotten a little further by changing my recursive function to make `count` a global variable and having `count=1` outside the function which has sorted out the getting all the values problem.

I have narrowed down the addition of extra keys to the `add_new_level` function, but haven't yet figured out how to change it.

Output:

```
{'value': {'value1': {2: {'arms': {'abdomen': {'legs': {'abdomen': {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}}}}}},
           'value2': {2: {'legs': {'abdomen': {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}}}},
           'value3': {5: {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}}}}
```

Comment: http://xyproblem.info/ ? Why do you want to create a *dictionary*? The output looks quite awkward. I mean I don't see how you would use it. My guess is that a *list* would a lot better choice.

Comment: It works for the purpose of what I'm doing. Hard to explain, but the hierarchy helps dictate the relationship of the data which is useful to me. I don't know what the hierarchy is beforehand or the data that may be in a relationship with the value, I just know that I want the value, then I can determine the useful information by checking it's branches. This is the *ahem* easiest and quickest way I could figure of getting the results I want.

Comment: same goes for lists. just the outermost layers has to be a dict.

Comment: While I could use a list for the values, their contents would still have to be in dict form unless I used an ordered list to maintain the order that the data comes in to know exactly the relationship it holds with the value. Plus I intend to expand this sideways as such, so extra data on each level could be recorded if I deem it useful. I've given a basic example dataset here; the real one is quite extensive.

Comment: If you come up with a good solution to my problem using lists, please feel free to post it as an answer... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted your output type slightly to make the dictionary containing 'value1' 'value2' etc... to an array. I believe this is better because the order of these will be lost anyway unless an OrderedDict (from collections package) is used and in any case an array will translate quite easily from index 0,1,2,3.. to val1, val2, val3, etc...

```
res = {'value': []}
def revnest(inp, keys=[]):
    res2 = res['value']
    if type(inp) == list:
        inp = {i:j[i] for j in inp for i in j}
    for x in inp:
        if x == 'value':
            res2.append({inp[x]:{}})
            res2 = res2[-1][inp[x]]
            for y in keys[::-1]:
                res2[y] = {}
                res2 = res2[y]
        else:
            revnest(inp[x], keys+[x])

revnest(exampleset)
print res
```

which given your exampleset, prints:

```
{'value': [{2: {'legs': {'abdomen': {'body': {}}}}}, {2: {'arms': {'abdomen': {'body': {}}}}}, {5: {'fingers': {'hands': {'body': {}}}}}]}
```

Comment: This works perfectly as the solution to my question, many thanks! I didn't know that you could index a list with [-1] (from the end?) or the keys[::-1] functionality. Learned something new. :)

Comment: glad i could help. keys[::-1] is the same as reversed(keys), but a bit more mathy :)

Comment: Huh. Didn't know about reversed(keys) either. Today is a double whammy of knowledge. Math[s]y is never bad! I'm always looking for different ways to implement solutions as I'm still a newbie to Python really. Maths I get though. This reminds me of Perl somewhat. Perl is really good for problems like this with solutions like yours.